# R image function plotting matrix incorrectly: overlayed or wrapped

Tags: image, r

I have a world map stored as matrix. Its dimensions are 64*128. But when I plotted the matrix using image() function, the picture is wrong, like the following

[image]

The problem is America overlaps with Eurasia. Here is the matrix data:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/87gce81dx0zcipq/temp.txt

Any suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to post the code that you used. That's just a text file and you cannot issue a command image("text"). You must have done some sort of read operation. And that's probably where the error lies.

Comment: Also... there are a huge number of NA's in there. Was this data created with R functions?

Comment: @Dwin - it works for me to replicate the OP's image doing a `read.table` and then `image(as.matrix(x))`. NA's are blanks in an `image` call, so that shouldn't be too unusual.

Comment: this would be quite characteristic of having gotten the dimensions of the matrix wrong, I think. e.g. `m <- outer(-50:50,-50:50,function(x,y) sqrt(x^2+y^2)); d <- 1.0*m<10 ; image(d); m2 <- matrix(c(m)[1:(49*50)],nrow=49); image(d2)`

Comment: hate to be picky, but I would suggest changing the title from "R image function can't plot a matrix correctly" to the more neutral "Difficulty plotting a matrix with image()" (you don't need to mention R in the title since it's in the tags, and more importantly I seriously doubt that `image()` **can't** plot a matrix correctly ...

Comment: I conclude that the image data most likely got screwed up somewhere along the line.  Without a really inspired guess I don't think I (at least) am going to be able to diagnose/fix without seeing more about where these data ultimately came from.

Comment: Yes it can, you should write an accurate title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at:

```
 image(as.matrix(dat[, (1:128)%%2==0])  ) #even number columns (Eastern Hemisphere)
```

[image]

```
 image(as.matrix(dat[, (1:128)%%2==1]) ) # odd numbers columns (Western Hemishere)
```

[image]

Comment: inspired guess! I'm impressed.

Comment: It was your comment that inspired it.

Comment: And join them together to sort it out: `image(rbind(as.matrix(dat[, (1:128)%%2==0]),as.matrix(dat[, (1:128)%%2==1])))` Poor old Tasmania, relegated to a single block.

Comment: Many thanks, guys. very impressive, but I'm still confused that the image() function does not map a matrix into a plot cell by cell.

Comment: As far as I can see it IS plotting cell by cell. Perhaps you do not understand that the row numbers are the implicit "x"-coordinates and that the column numbers are the implicit "y"-coordinates? See the help page for image where this is explicitly stated. So the documentation does warn you that the image will be rotated "90 degree counter-clockwise [compared to] the conventional printed layout of a matrix." Your data effectively interleaved the column positions so you got interleaving along the y-axis and that horizontal striping effect.